# Conditional linking of library XCODE simulator vs. build for device

Tags: ios, xcode

Question: I want CoreAudioKit.framework to only be included when building for device. When building for simulator, if CoreAudioKit.framework is included, it will throw an error since it is not supported in simulator. Any ideas other than manually doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to approach this, one way is to check via precompiler directives for the hardware type to load certain libraries. So at the top of your `.m` you could include:

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
#endif
```

Comment: OK weird. I commented out #import <CoreAudioKit/CoreAudioKit.h>. Added the library as optional and I still get the linker error. ld: framework not found CoreAudioKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Status to "Optional" instead of "Required" for CoreAudioKit.framework in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries?